# Multiple AJAX Requests for one JSF/Seam change

Tags: java, seam, ajax4jsf

I'm using this code to update some parts of a page:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{shopPerformanceManager.shopId}" id="shopSelect">
    <s:selectItems value="#{shopPerformanceManager.employeeShops}" var="selectShop"
        label="#{selectShop.name}" itemValue="#{selectShop.id}" />
    <a:ajax event="change" render=":myElem1 :myElem2 :myElem3" listener="#{shopPerformanceManager.refresh}"
        oncomplete="paintGraphs()" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Now the problem with this is that it produces **one** AJAX request and one response, after which myElem1, myElem2 and myElem3 are rendered. What I want instead are **three** separate requests and responses, so that the elements are processed in parallel and shown ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

you can use many a:ajax tag in the same selectOneMenu, look

`<h:selectOneMenu>
    <s:selectItems />
    <a:ajax event="change" listener="#{listener1}" />
    <a:ajax event="change" listener="#{listener2}" />
    <a:ajax event="change" listener="#{listener3}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>`

Comment: Tried that but it seems multiple ajax elements are optimized to one. I used the same code as you above except I only changed the 'render' attribute instead of 'listener'. I viewed the traffic through the browser dev tools and found out that there were multiple requests with the same content and response.